# What will be the current flows through the following circuit?

Tags: current-measurement

[image: Circuit]

I`m confusing to see a textbook there is no current flows through the 7 ohm resistor. But why? And what will be the total current flowing through the circuit?

Comment: If your textbook says no current flows through the 7Ω resistor, your textbook is wrong.

Comment: Can you name the textbook, please?

Comment: I’m wondering if you mis-entered the schematic? Did the original have both sides of the 7 ohm resistor connected to ground? If so, they are right, no current would flow through it because it is shorted out.

Comment: You should share an image of the actual diagram as it appears in the textbook, in case you missed some important detail when copying it to our drawing too.

Comment: Example of @The Photon comment: when there is a GND symbol in the left corner of the schematic as well (between the the voltage source and the 7ohm resistor). In that case, no current flows through the 7ohm resistor.

Answer (score 3):

If your textbook says that no current flows through the 7Ω resistor, your textbook is wrong. There will be a current of 0.5 amperes through every resistor in the circuit, and no current into the ground node.